# Using \pgfpointanchor in the background path of a circuit symbol shape

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-circuit-lib, tikz-shape

I have tried to create a circuit symbol for general sources as used in physics textbooks for high schools:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.ee.IEC,shapes.gates.ee}
\makeatletter
\pgfdeclareshape{mybox}{%
  \inheritsavedanchors[from=rectangle ee]
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{center}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{north}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{south}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{north east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{north west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{south east}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{south west}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{input}
  \inheritanchor[from=rectangle ee]{output}
  \inheritanchorborder[from=rectangle ee]
  \inheritbackgroundpath[from=rectangle ee]
\anchor{west circ center}{
\pgfpointlineattime{0.5}{\southwest}{\northeast}
\advance\pgf@x by-0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit%
}
\anchor{east circ center}{
\pgfpointlineattime{0.5}{\southwest}{\northeast}
\advance\pgf@x by0.5\tikzcircuitssizeunit%
}
\backgroundpath{%
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{west}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{west circ center}}
\pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{east}}
\pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{east circ center}}
\pgfusepath{stroke}
\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{east circ center}}{0.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
\pgfpathcircle{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@fig@name}{west circ center}}{0.25\tikzcircuitssizeunit}
\pgfusepath{stroke,fill}
}
}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
  circuit declare symbol=general source,
  set general source graphic={
     draw,fill=white,shape=mybox, circuit symbol size=width 3 height 1,
    transform shape,
    }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
\draw(0,0)to[general source={info={foo}}](2,0)to[resistor={info=bar}](4,0);
\draw(0,0)to[resistor](0,-3)to[make contact](4,-3)to[bulb](4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The `\backgroundpath` is drawn using commands like `\pgfpathlineto` and `\pgfpointanchor`, which works at my machine. `tikz` itself defines its own derived shapes using background paths with hard calculations based solely on `\southwest` and `\northeas` which looks cumbersome to me, once the other anchors are established.

Is there any harm or risk in my way and should I switch to `tikz`'s way, or can I leave it like this?

Comment: The reason tikz code looks so odd is that it is plain tex compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you are not wrong. It is up to you whether it is worth it.

---

The PGF manual makes it clear that `\anchor`, in contrast to `\savedanchor`, is a **create-on-demand** object. That is, an anchor's coordinate is calculated only if the user explicitly write `(A.east)`.

This saves a lot of time because 90% of anchors are not used at all and we should not waste any time calculating them.

---

When Ti*k*Z is drawing the background path, these `\anchor`'s coordinates are not calculated yet. If Ti*k*Z calculates these coordinates just for the  drawing then it is pointless to use `\anchor` at the first place... simply make everything `\savedanchor`.

So it is not about TeX-compatibility. Ti*k*Z prefer pure TeX-code because they are faster. The author decides to spend two more hours to save millions of people two seconds. In my opinion, we should say that Ti*k*Z is designed for TeX, and is compatible with LaTeX.

---

In your case, it is all up to you. Do you want to write simple codes and wait for couple more milliseconds? Or you rather playing with `\pgf@x`? I personally prefer the former.